# Failing to automatically re-connect to New PRIMARY after a replica set failover , from Mongoose (MongoDB, NodeJS Driver)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I made a simple NodeJS App, with Mongoose as MongoDB Driver. And connected to a mongodb replica set. The App is working fine until I shut down the current primary, When the PRIMARY is down, the replica set automatically elected a new PRIMARY. But, after that the node application doesn't seems to be responding for DB queries.

**CODE: DB Connection**

```
var options = { 
    server: { 
        socketOptions: { 
            keepAlive: 1, 
            connectTimeoutMS:30000, 
            socketTimeoutMS:90000 } 
        },
    replset: { 
        socketOptions: { 
            keepAlive: 1, 
            connectTimeoutMS : 30000 , 
            socketTimeoutMS: 90000  
        }, 
        rs_name: 'rs0' 
     } };

var uri = "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/rstest";

 mongoose.connect(uri,options);
```

**CODE: DB Query**

```
  router.('/test',function(req,res){

     var testmodel = new testModel('test') ;
     testmodel.save(function (err, doc,numberAffected) {
         if (err) {
             console.log("ERROR: "+ err);
             res.status = 404;
             res.end;
         }else{
             console.log("Response sent ");
             res.status = 200;
             res.end;
         }
     });
 });
```

**Steps Followed**

1. Created a MongoDB replica set in three VMs.
2. Created a simple nodeJS App (Express + Mongoose) with a test API as above
3. Sent GET request to 'test' continuously with some time interval to the app from a local system.
4. Took the PRIMARY instance down
5. Console will log "ERROR: Error: connection closed"
6. APPLICATION STOPPED RESPONDING TO REQUESTS

Varsions: 
    "express": "4.10.6",
    "mongodb": "1.4.23",
    "mongoose": "3.8.21",

A sample app that I have done for debugging this issue is available at https://melvingeorge@bitbucket.org/melvingeorge/nodejsmongorssample.git

I am not sure if this is a bug or some mis-configuration from my end. How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Write operations are made only on master instance. It will take some time for replica set to select a new primary server.

from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/replica-sets/

> How long does replica set failover take?
>
> It varies, but a replica set will select a new primary within a
>   minute.
>
> It may take 10-30 seconds for the members of a replica set to declare
>   a primary inaccessible. This triggers an election. During the
>   election, the cluster is unavailable for writes.
>
> The election itself may take another 10-30 seconds.

check your code with read operations (find/count)

as long as there is not a master instance, you can't do write operations

Comment: I know that, but it's not the reason. Its not getting reconnected even after a new primary gets elected. I means, it hangs forever.

Comment: maybe your script is not connecting to replica set, but only to the master server?

Comment: no, I gave the options as
    var options = {
        auto_reconnect: true,
        db: {
            bufferMaxEntries:0
    
        },
        replSet: {
        socketOptions:
            {
                connectTimeoutMS : 30000,
                keepAlive: 1
            }
        }
    };
I am getting error message,

Comment: Hi @arv1989, did you find any solution to this issue? I encountered similar issues in my application (I'm using mongodb 3.2, and driver version 2.1). it looks like the node js mongo driver gets stuck when master changes, even though the mongo shell shows the new topology immediately in rs.status() (the app and mongo runs on the same machine). hope you have any insights

Answer (score 0):

The 'rs_name' in replset options is necessary to specify a replicaSet. You can use `mongoose.createConnection(uri, conf, callback)` and get final conf in callback.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this got fixed in [NODE-818 / 2.2.10](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-818).

But I am using 2.2.22 and still have a problem like that.

Upon reconnect, the mongo client reconnects to a a secondary instead of a newly selected primary which then is, I cannot write to the database.

My connection string is like `mongodb://mongo1,mongo2,mongo3/db?replicaSet=rs`